# SHIFT+F2 does not create a horizontal split in byobu in tmux mode (using Putty SSH client)

Tags: debian, ssh, tmux, putty, byobu

SHIFT+F2 does not create a horizontal split in byobu in tmux mode (using Putty client from Windows 7).

SHIFT+F2 just gives me '~' in the terminal.

Byobu installed on Debian 8.11.

Using byobu version:

```
byobu -v
byobu version 5.87
tmux 2.3
```

Any idea why SHIFT+F2 is not working in byobu?

Comment: @dustin-kirkland any idea?

Comment: `Any idea why SHIFT+F2 is not working in byobu?` ... how do you know that the problem is with byobu? ... have you tried it on a local terminal, not on an SSH connection from windows 7?

Comment: Well, because splitting works from tmux.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a different SSH client. I used MobaXterm and it only accepted vertical split, but when I used Windows terminal (`cmd.exe`) it worked as expected.

Comment: cmd.exe if far from a good command line terminal. This is why I use Putty, which is more versatile.